# Mock the value of a service inside directive's unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner

Inside my directive's instantiation I have a call to a method that returns some data:

`data = myService.getData()`

and later in the code I am doing
`something = data[id]`

In karma I have an error, cannor read id of undefined, meaning that `data` is undefined.

I tried to mock the call to the service like:

`spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.returnValue(mockData);`

but the problem remains. **How can mock the `data` inside my tests?**

```
 # Injector
  beforeEach(inject(($injector) ->

    $compile = $injector.get('$compile')
    $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope')
    $scope = $rootScope.$new()
    $httpBackend = $injector.get('$httpBackend')
    myService = $injector.get('myService')

    element = angular.element('<my-directive id="0"></my-directive>')
    template = $compile(element)($scope)
    $scope.$digest()

    spyOn(myService, 'getData').and.returnValue(someMockData)
  ))
```

Comment: Not to be silly but where have you defined someMockData?

Comment: @mikeswright49 in the top of the file. is definitely defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of using the actual service, create a jasmine spy.

```
var myService = jasmine.createSpyObj('myService', ['getData']);

beforeEach(inject(($injector, $provide) => {

     // injector.gets ... don't get 'myService'
     . . . 

     $provide.value('myService', myService);

}))

it('should return data from service', () => {

    myService.getData.andReturn(['your mocked data']);

    // rest of test

})
```

Comment: when I am inject the `provider` like you do, I have `Unknown provider: $providerProvider <- $provider`

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. It should be `$provide`. Ill update the original answer.